# Dynamically changing the recursion limit for a fibonnacci program python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, fibonacci

I am trying to write a recursive multinacci (basically fibonacci numbers except the rabbits produce k pairs instead of 1 pair with each breeding cycle) function and I want it to work with all n. Here is my code so far:

```
from functools import lru_cache
from sys import getrecursionlimit, setrecursionlimit

def fibnum(n, k=1):
    """Returns the nth fibonacci number of order k"""
    # check if recursionlimit needs increasing
    return _fibnum(n, k)

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def _fibnum(n, k):
    if n <= 0:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return _fibnum(n-1, k) + k * _fibnum(n-2, k)
```

A few notes about the code: the first function is a wrapper around the second so as to the description text look right. The second function is memoized, which increases performance drastically.

I've noticed that when I try to find increasing values of `fibnum` in order (100, 400, 1000 etc.) I can get around the recursion limit since the memoization shortcuts the recursion. I want to be able to run my function for any number right off the bat. I've tried testing the bounds of the recursion limit for n and then setting the recursion limit to that, but the only one that seemed to work was n<sup>2</sup>, but that seems too high of a limit.

Any suggestions?

Note: at a later point, I would like to add a lifespan to the formula (which is basically subtract out fibnum(n- life_span, k)). How would this affect the recursion depth needed?

Comment: You could `try`, catch the `RuntimeError` and double the recursion limit then (up to some larger max - eventually you'll have to give in!)

Comment: IMHO, for Python the idiomatic way to write fib is converting the algorithm from recursive to iterative.

Comment: Also: isn't `lru_cache` in `functools` (not `itertools`), and doesn't it preserve documentation (although admittedly not signature)?

Comment: Yeah sorry it is in functools, updated code to match.

Comment: Also the main point I was making is that I don't have to give in. If I run my code with ever increasing n (100, 200, 300... 10000), it can go on forever because of the memoization. I've tried it myself and it works, despite retaining the default recursion depth. I want to be able to do this automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of sidestepping the stack limitations is to set up the Fibonacci recurrence in [matrix form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form) and use the matrix version of multiplication by successive halving and squaring.  With this approach the stack growth is O(log n), so you can go to gigantic values of fib(n) with no worries.  Here's an implementation:

```
def __matrix_fib__(n):
    if n == 1:
        return [0, 1]
    else:
        f = __matrix_fib__(n / 2)
        c = f[0] * f[0] + f[1] * f[1]
        d = f[1] * (f[1] + 2 * f[0])
        if n % 2 == 0:
            return [c, d]
        else:
            return [d, c + d]


def fib(n):
    assert (n >= 0)
    if n == 0:
        return n
    else:
        return __matrix_fib__(n)[1]
```

**ADDENDUM**

This version adds the `k` parameter as requested...

```
def __matrix_fib__(n, k):
    if n == 1:
        return [0, 1]
    else:
        f = __matrix_fib__(n / 2, k)
        c = k * f[0] * f[0] + f[1] * f[1]
        d = f[1] * (f[1] + 2 * k * f[0])
        if n % 2 == 0:
            return [c, d]
        else:
            return [d, k * c + d]


def fib(n, k=1):
    assert (n >= 0)
    if n == 0:
        return n
    else:
        return __matrix_fib__(n, k)[1]
```

I won't swear this is correct because I dashed it off between classes, but my tests produced the same answers as your version when given the same inputs.

Comment: How would I modify this to add the k factor that is in my original code?

Comment: `__matrix_fib__(n, k)[1] = [Fib(n-1, k), Fib(n, k)][1] = Fib(n, k)` http://nayuki.eigenstate.org/page/fast-fibonacci-algorithms http://nayuki.eigenstate.org/res/fast-fibonacci-algorithms/fastFibonacci.py

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use a class as a namespace to store the cache, then calculate results iteratively:

```
class Fib(object):
    cache = [1, 1]

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, n):
        if n < 1:
            return 0

        for i in range(len(cls.cache), n):
            cls.cache.append(cls.cache[-1] + cls.cache[-2])

        return cls.cache[n - 1]
```

Usage:

```
a = Fib()
print a.get(1000)
```

Comment: Or more generally, calculate values from the bottom up rather than from the top down. This doesn't require a class, but it sure makes it convenient.

Comment: Yeah, it could be done other ways but that's a handy way to hold state without resorting to global variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you change `fibnum` to limit the call stack to 100 items by computing the first 100 fibnums, then the next 100 fibnums, then the next 100 fibnums, you can avoid a recursion limit.

This produces very little wasted work since you'll need to compute the first 100 fibnums to compute the last 100 fibnums anyways.

The number 100 is arbitrary, but should be less than `sys.recursionlimit`.

```
def fibnum(n, k=1):
    """Returns the nth fibonacci number of order k"""
    # build up cache of fib values early in the sequence
    for intermediate_n in range(100, n, 100):
        _fibnum(intermediate_n, k)
    return _fibnum(n, k)
```

Comment: I tried it with 500 and it didn't seem to work, even when recursion limit is 1000. This does work with up to somewhere around 300-400, and it definitely fails at 400. It does work with 100 though. Also, I think that it would be good to store the limit as a global variable so that we don't do useless computations every time.

Comment: Hmm.. It works on my system for 500 and 1500. My recursion limit is 1000. Check your lru_cache implementation. I'm using Jython 2.5 and this memoized decorator (since functools.lru_cache was added in Python 3): https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize

Comment: I'm using Python 3.4 with python's native functools.lru_cache implementation, if I understand correctly.

Comment: What is `lru_cache.cache_info()` after you get a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`?

Comment: It says function object lru_cache has no attribute cache_info

Comment: Sorry. What is `_fibnum.cache_info()`. That will tell you your `currsize` to see if the cache is being used. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache If you use the `memoized` decorator do you still get a max recursion depth error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58836/discussion-between-iceardor-and-mleyfman).